# Suppose that $f'(z)$ exists on $\mathbb{C}$ and $\Im(f'(z))=6x(2y-1)$, $f(0)=3-2i$ and $f(1)=5-5i$. Find $f(1+i)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f'(z)$ exists on $\mathbb{C}$ and $\Im(f'(z))=6x(2y-1)$, $f(0)=3-2i$ and $f(1)=5-5i$. Find $f(1+i)$.

I think $f'$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, but I don't know how to complete. Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Since $f'$ exists on $\mathbb C$, it follows that $f$ is entire, and hence $f'$ is also entire.

Therefore, as you said, $f'$ satisfies the CR equations.

Let $f'(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. Then, you are told that $v(x,y)=6x(2y-1)$.

You can use the Cauchy Riemann equations to find $u$ up to a constant.

Use $f'(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ together with $x=\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}, y=\frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}$ to get $f'(z)$ as a function in $z$.

This gives you $f'$ and by integration you can get $f$, with two constants.

$f(0)$ and $f(1)$ tell you what these constants are, therefore, you get $f(z)$.

Comment: @RobertDavis You know that $x=\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}$ and $y=\frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}$. By doing this $f$ becomes a function in $z$, and since $\bar{z}$ is nowhere differentiable, the terms with $\bar{z}$ will cancel eachother...

Comment: @RobertDavis What did you get for $f'$?

Comment: @RobertDavis Simple example$f'(z)=2z-1$. What is$f(z)$? BTW: I told you step by step what to do, but you jump directly to step 3, that's why you are confused...

Comment: I obtain $u=6x^2+6y-6y^2+c=6(z^2+\bar{z}^2)-3i(z-\bar{z})+c$. The $\bar{z}$ didn't cancel each other. Are you certain of your method? I don't understand at all!

Comment: @RobertDavis So what is $f'$? I said that the $\bar{z}$ should cancel in $f$ not in $u$ ;)

Comment: So I obtain $(6(z^2+\bar{z}^2)-3i(z-\bar{z}))+i(-3((z^2-\bar{z}^2)i+(z+\bar{z})))=9z^2 +3\bar{z}-i6z$. Could you tell me the next step, because I don't see it? And I reverified  the equation, I don't see how to cancel $\bar{z}$.

Comment: @RobertDavis The bars didn't cancel, which means that you already did a mistake, so there is no need to go to the next step yet, you have first to find your mistake. Check again the steps when you went from $x,y$ to $z,\bar{z}$, note that $$x^2=\left( \frac{z+\bar{z}}{2} \right)^2$$ and I think you forgot to square the denominator.

Comment: What is the advantage of using this method, then we can use Cauchy-Riemann?

Comment: @RobertDavis When you find $f'(z)$ you can check your answer by replacing $z=x+iy$. If you plug $z=x+iy$ into $ 9z^2 +3\bar{z}-i6z$ you do not get $u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, and this tells you that there is a mistake in your computations.

Comment: @RobertDavis What do you mean the advantage of this method? As opposite to what? CR equations allow you to find one of $u,v$ if you know the other, and this is exactly the first step we do. If we know $u$ and $v$, we can combine them in our function...But we are given the imaginary part of $f'$ not $f$, which means that at this point we find $f'$. From here, next step is to figure what f is ...

Comment: Yes, but using Cauchy-Riemann equations you get something like this, I think
$$f '(z)=u_x(x,y)+iv_x(x,y)=v_y(x,y)-iu_y(x,y)$$
From here, you can get the answer
$$f(z)=f(x,y)=f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$$

Comment: @RobertDavis And what is $v$? Because the $v$ you are using is the imaginary part of $f'$ not the imaginary part of $f$! If you want, you can denote by $g=f'$ and use the CR equations for $g$.... Because you know the imaginary part of $f'$ you are using the CR equations for $f'$ NOT for $f$.

Comment: @RobertDavis Or if you want to go on this route you started, the problem tells you that $Im(f')=6x(2y-1)$. This means that $$v_x(x,y)=-u_y(x,y)=6x(2y-1)$$ Try to find $u,v$ from here.

Comment: One last question : "By doing this $f$ becomes a function in $z$, and since $z¯$ is nowhere differentiable, the terms with $z¯ $will cancel eachother...'' How do you know this is true? I don't understand why it works

Comment: @RobertDavis This comes from experience, but is a bit subtle so I would not expect my students to see this. Here is why this must be the case in this problem. First $v(x,y)$ is a polynomial of degree 2 in two variables, which together with CR implies that so is $u(x,y)$. Therefore, after replacing $x,y$ by $z, \bar{z}$ we will get a polynomial in $z, \bar{z}$ of degree 2. Thus, I knew that the answer will have the form $$f'=az^2+bz \bar{z} + c \bar{z}^2+dz +e \bar{z}+f$$ Since this is entire, subtracting the entire function $az^2+dz +f$ we get that $$bz \bar{z} + c \bar{z}^2+e \bar{z}$$

Comment: is entire. Now, by adding the right function of the form $\alpha z^2 + \beta z$ you can write this in the form $u^2+ \gamma u$ where $u$ has the form $u= (\sqrt{c} \bar{z} + \sqrt{\alpha} z)$ . Finally, as $u^2+ \gamma u$ is entire as a function in $u$, and $\sqrt{c} \bar{z} + \sqrt{\alpha} z$ is nowhere differentiable unless $c=0$, it is easy to show that the composition between an entire function and a nowhere differentiable function is non-differentiable at all points where the derivative of the entire function is zero.

Comment: By this argument we can get that $c=0$  and by playing the same game two more times you get $b=e=0$....... Rule of thumb:  If a polynomial in $z, \bar{z}$ is entire, it has to be a Polynomial in $z$.